# Add a Pascal rule on ACE web editor

Tags: javascript, regex, editor, ace-editor

I am using ACE web editor for coding in pascal language and a want to add a rule in the mode-pascal.js native file.

What I want is to highlight all 'read' and 'write' keywords in all lines begining with 'property' and ending with ';'.

Something like :

```
property Lala : Integer read (123) write (456);
```

But not :

```
var read := "write";
```

And with ACE... I need to do that with only one regexp, fun.

If someone have an idea, it can save a life !

Comment: So you wish to select whole line with read and write word ?

Comment: It is impossible with a single regex (if it is not .NET or PyPi regex).

Comment: @Rahul just "read" and "write", not the whole line, and there can be several of it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think too, maybe it's possible to do it manually but I don't find how in the ACE doc.

Comment: Yeah, that is why the question is too broad, off-topic, for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ace syntax highlighter supports states similar to textmate and sublime.
That means you can match `property` keyword, and switch to a state that highlights `read` and `write`, something like this:

```
[
...
{
   regex: /property\b/
   token: "keyword",
   next: [
       {
           regex: /(read|write)\b/
           token: "keyword",
       },
       { include: "start" }, // include other rules if you want
       {
           regex: "$|;", 
           token: "text",
           next: "start" // exit the property state on line end or ;
       }
   ]
}
...
```